# EF migration - default value for string

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-migration

I'm trying to update DB using EF migration (Code-First). I want to add a new string column which should contain a default value, so I create migration like this:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.SupplierCodeMappings", "SupplierCompanyCode", 
                  c => c.String(defaultValueSql:"'X'"));
}
```

I generate a script from it, which looks also OK by my opinion.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SupplierCodeMappings] ADD [SupplierCompanyCode] [nvarchar](max) DEFAULT 'X'
INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'201709221530217_AddSupplierMappingCompanyCode', N'Ea.Data.Database.EaContext', xxxxxx , N'6.1.3-40302')
```

However, when I run it against the DB, the new column has `NULL` value for all rows.
(I've also tried a variant with `defaultValue:"X"` in migration, without success).

I've used a default value many times before with different types (int, DateTime) and it has worked every time, is there some special behavior for strings?

Comment: Might be the default value is not inserted because the column is nullable, however that would be a weird behavior. Does it work when you make the column not nullable (.IsRequired, [Required])?

Comment: Good idea, I've added `nullable: false` to the migration and it works. However, I believe it should be able to fill some the value anyway, it sounds a bit like some bug to me.

Comment: depends on your point of view I guess. I would say default value should be when otherwise there would be null. However, you could also argue that for a nullable column, null is a valid value. In SQL standard, the default value is used IF no other value is specified; for the migration, it appears the value null is specific enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DevilSuichiro suggested in comments, filling the default value works just when the field/column is non-nullable. I don't know if it's planned behavior but it looks like it works this way in EF/SQL now.

So this works as expected:

```
AddColumn("dbo.SupplierCodeMappings", "SupplierCompanyCode", 
              c => c.String(nullable: false, defaultValueSql:"'X'"));
```